# same user at the same time on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, users

I want to known if its possible for the same user to be logon at the same time on windows 7 machine, like Linux.

I tried to use some RDP but they just can logon different users.

Does anybody know some process to do that?

Comment: This isn't possible on Windows 7, even if you use the hack, that lets you connect multiple users hack

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to build is called a [Terminal Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Terminal_Server), and my understanding is that it requires special [licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770371%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft to allow concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as in Linux won't work but you can log one session directly and a second one using a tool called "psexec", this one is a Microsoft approved tool part of the sysinternals, it will allow you to log on non interactively and run some programs in this secondary session.
Another option is to use powershell to run more sessions using it's command line interface but this needs some configuration prior to using it.
And the more appropriate way to have the same user logged on and interactively and on GUI twice is installing and configuring terminal server.